# Reviewing edited closed questions that could be re-opened

Tags: support, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

Is there a way for mods/normal users to view closed questions that could be reopened due to edits?

An example would be this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8572913/c-sharp-exception-when-getting-rgb-values-of-bitmap

I edited it pretty quickly, but after it was closed. It got a couple of re-open votes, but not enough so it remains closed.

Is there any mechanism for this post to get picked up by someone and re-opened (hopefully before OP has gone elsewhere)?